# Is it Possible to Use Imported Class Methods in A Python Class Definition Without Running All Code In the Imported File?

Tags: python, file, import, structure, pymol

I am using the PyMOL molecular viewer as a subset of a larger program, and for ease of reading am breaking up my files like so...

```
### command1ClassFile.py

class command1Class():
    def command1(self):
        print "do action 1, this requires pymol functions"

### command2ClassFile.py

class command2Class():
    def command2(self):
        print "do action 2, this also requires pymol functions"

### mainModule.py

import command1ClassFile, command2ClassFile

class commandsClass(command1Class, command2Class):
    pass


class guiClass(parentClass, commandsClass):
    def onLeftClick(self):
        self.command1()

    def onRightClick(self):
        self.command2()

# this imports the module as well as launching the program, unfortunately
import pymol
pymol.finish_launching()
```

I can't just add "import pymol" to the beginning of the other files, because that would launch the program multiple times. I can solve this by just using one .py file, but that leads to an excessively large source file.

I did not catch anyone's interest on the PyMOL mailing list, so I was hoping there was some other way around this. If not, is there a better way to break up code? I am used to being spoiled by header files in C++, and the architecture of Python projects is bit difficult for me to handle properly.

EDIT: For different cases, is using multiple inheritance across files and dummy compilation classes in this way a good way to structure python projects with complicated methods?

Comment: I'm not familiar with PyMOL, but how about passing the PyMOL functions to the `command` methods?

Comment: You might try something like `from pymol import command1, command2, class1`.

Comment: @Robᵩ: That'll still compile and execute the top-level statements in the module first.

Comment: Looking at the [module source code](http://sourceforge.net/p/pymol/code/4008/tree/trunk/pymol/modules/pymol/__init__.py) I see a complex web of launching code. Perhaps something can be tweaked to change how it starts, though I don't have enough time to work out what exactly.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters Unfortunately this is for several people in a lab to use and I don't have the skill yet to edit the program usefully without causing havoc on different system versions. I was hoping that there might be some hackish way around this, but if not I will just deal with giant source files.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, that's what `if __name__ == '__main__'` is for.

Comment: That is what PyMOL *should* be using but apparently is not. Won't help the OP one bit here.

Comment: In that case, I'd likely take a look at PyMOL, see what's going on in the source file and either a) report a bug detailing the functionality you're after, b) make a change and contribute a patch that allows the behaviour you're after or c) monkey-patch PyMOL (if possible) to achieve the desired functionality.

Comment: I linked to the source code in my comment to the question itself. It uses `__main__` tests but it's a little more convoluted than that...

Comment: Eesh. You weren't kidding ;) A bit of digging required there. More time required than I have atm unfortunately.

Comment: That does not help with this specific problem, but is good to know for the future.